# Reopen a closed window with all its tabs in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, window-restore

**Updated note**: The version of Microsoft Edge I experienced this problem with predates the switch to the Chromium under-pinnings, wherein this problem does not exist.
EG <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> should work for you.

I've closed a Microsoft Edge (25.10586.0.0) window that had multiple old tabs on it restored over multiple starts, while unawares that I'd minimized a single window with nothing important on it. Now if I quit edge, when I next start it with "reopen last session" it will only open the unimportant window and not the important (recently closed one).

I can try <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> but it reopens only tabs specific to the remaining window's history.
If I look in the history, which I cannot search, I am amazed to not see very many of the tabs I just closed. EG a Docker image for Apache Drill, some Github pages etc.

Is reopening the last closed window with all it's tabs a missing feature? This is infuriating. Is there a work around?

Comment: I've seen a 50+ up voted request for this in the Windows Insider Feedback app. So maybe not yet?

Comment: Someone kindly notify me with a comment when Edge adds this missing feature. I've stopped using it until that day.

Comment: Hey @dlamblin, you can now do this using the new Set Aside Tabs features in Edge on Windows 10.

Comment: @VirgilShelton But if you close a window you haven't set aside any of its tabs, so, you don't actually get to reopen them. It's odd like that.

Comment: yes that's true but that's why I said it's not easy :)

Comment: That this issue still exists end of 2023 is unbelievable! As I am used to Firefox I closed 3 Edge windows yesterday and now I have only one left, which of course isn't the main window that had multiplte tabs opened well organised in groups. Unbelievable, absolutely unbelievable. :|

Comment: @Andreas It shouldn't still be in 2023's Edge. You should be able to see in the history view when you closed a window as something like "4 tabs closed" and be able to select from a context menu "Restore all tabs" from that one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The same thing just happened to me (I had multiple windows open and accidentally closed one that had several important tabs). In a panic I searched for a way to restore the closed window, and came across this very question. From the other answer and the comments, my heart began to sink. But then I realized that they are outdated!

This is how it works in recent versions of Edge (which are based on Chromium). If you close a window containing more than 1 tab, *and* if you have yet to open any new tab in any other window, then you can reopen the closed window either by right-clicking on the tab area in any of the remaining open windows, *or* by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> as indicated in the picture below.

[image: Reopen closed window]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now. This just helped me out tremendously. Thanks!

Comment: What if you closed a window unknowingly, and you've opened and closed a bunch of tabs in the meantime?  Are you just hosed?

Comment: Clarification: just keep on pressing Ctrl+Shift+T and it will keep on opening closed tabs and windows. This works like Ctrl+Z that usually has a history of undos that you can keep on recovering. So, it does not matter if you have opened other tabs since the accidental closure of the important window.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work if all windows were closed, which is kinda easy thanks to Windows 11's  wonderful grouping of taskbar icons.

Comment: I just closed a window and after pressing ctrl-shift-T several times (reopening tabs in the current window) a new browser window appeared, but with the same tabs as the other window, not the tabs that were in the closed window. So now I have two windows with same tabs. Windows 11, Edge 120.0.2210.121

Comment: Wait, now I see the window I wanted is also there. So I have window 1, window 2 and a clone of window1. Weird. At least I got the missing window 2 back.

Answer (score 2):

You can now do this using the new Microsoft Edge feature that ships with the [Creators Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/features) in Windows 10, it's called "[Set these tabs aside](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-new-set-these-tabs-aside-feature-in-microsoft-edge/)".

While it's not as easy as simply clicking Exit on Chrome or Firefox you can indeed have many New Browser instances open, reboot and click Tabs You've Set Aside and successfully restore your previous browser state.

Edit:

Now with the [Chromium](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download) version of Edge out, this issue is now fixed.

Comment: This still doesn't answer when you accidentally close a window (eg press alt+f4 when closing the wrong window)

Comment: If you accidentally close Edge you should enabled Settings > Open Microsoft Edge with "Previous Pages" and you'll be protected.

Comment: The problem being that if you've got multiple windows open as well as tabs and you accidentally close your main window then its lost for good.  You have to recreate it by painstakingly scrolling through your history to look at the various dates they were all visited.

Comment: ... Even if you generally stick to one window browsing, other sites can sometimes open windows in the background (status windows, pop out chat dialog) and so closing your main window, leaves you with Edge still running, but unable to go back to that window.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Ignores the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible to do which is fantastic!

1. Right-click at the top of your window and from the context menu select reopen Closed Window

[image]

2. When the window appears right click and select restore window
3. Hey presto you have recovered from the so easy-to-do accidental window closing when you have other windows open too - and who doesn't these days!!

Comment: This doesn't work if you've opened any tabs after closing the window.  I had a named window with multiple named groups in it that vanished some time this morning, and I cannot find any trace of it in History.  :(